# Get with NodeJS and Axios to a IoT broker

Tags: json, node.js, curl, axios

I want to create an IoT entity in a broker that I have deployed in a virtual machine. For the moment I have communicated through curls and it works correctly.

Consultation with "curl":

```
(curl http://192.168.56.103:8080/ngsi10/updateContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
    "contextElements": [{
        "entityId": {
            "id": "01",
            "type": "example"
        },
        "attributes": [{
            "name": "numbers",
            "type": "int",
            "contextValue": 24
        }],
        "domainMetadata": [{
            "name": "location",
            "type": "point",
            "value": {
                "latitude": 37.982636,
                "longitude": -1.123510
            }
        }]
    }],
    "updateAction": "UPDATE"
}
EOF
```

This is working properly for me.

And this is the equivalent code of nodejs using axios:

```
var config = {
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'}
  };

  var dataJSon = [{
    "contextElements": [{
        "entityId": {
            "id": "01",
            "type": "example"
        },
        "attributes": [{
            "name": "numbers",
            "type": "int",
            "contextValue": 24
        }],
        "domainMetadata": [{
            "name": "location",
            "type": "point",
            "value": {
                "latitude": 37.982636,
                "longitude": -1.123510
            }
        }]
    }],
    "updateAction": "UPDATE"
}];

  const payload = {
    topic: 'topic',
    logs: dataJSon,
  };

  axios.get('http://192.168.56.103:8080/ngsi10/updateContext', dataJSon, config)
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
    // always executed
  });
```

When executing this last one the broker tells me that he does not understand it, I have snorted the request with wireshark and he is not doing it well, the data does not appear and only one header appears to me. Los contenidos de los datos son JSON.

I'll put it over here in case someone gives me a hand. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) with [`-d`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d) send a POST request. Use [`axios.post`](https://github.com/axios/axios#example) :

```
axios.post('http://192.168.56.103:8080/ngsi10/updateContext', dataJSon, config)
```